# Can't control z-index

Tags: css

I can't manage to control z-index anymore, I'd like to put a brown ribbon from pages 2-6 in front of logo, but it's not listening to me anymore even with huge z-index, can you point me the right direction of solving this issue? I tried multiple solution with rearranging div's structure but they were unefficient.

here's developer server where the project stays:

```
http://178.62.215.130/SV/#contact
```

my output is:

[image]

and i'd like to put that ribbon in front of logo.
logo is being displayed as fixed, as a part of nav with z-index = 70. I really want to add some code or something but don't know what could be helppful. I don;t want anybody to do my job, need a tip what can be causing this.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If z-index is not working then it's usually because you are trying to control element with static position. For z-index to work [you have to use](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) `position: absolute;`, `position: relative;` or `position:fixed;`.

UPDATE:
I think the problem is your HTML structure + its positioning which is unnecessarily complex - e.g. the ribbon is placed inside relatively positioned element which is placed in a fixed element which is placed in relative element again. If I put a div outside of that structure I can position it relatively easily where I want (using left, top and z-index properties). In your case the problem is probably the relative positioning which [resets positioning context for nested elements](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/). [Here](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) is another interesting resource.

Comment: I tried that, logo and ribbon are fixed and z-index of the h2 with ribbon background is 999 and the logo z-index is 70.

background: url('wp-content/themes/so-vintage.com/img/common/ribbon.png') no-repeat scroll 0px -20px transparent;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999 !important;
width: 600px !important;
height: 100px !important;
position: fixed;
top: 13.35%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);